# SQL -Update Table2 with data from Table1, but do not update exact duplicates in Table2

Tags: sql-server

[2 tables involved] I need to get the Tracking # from TABLE1 and give that value to the Tracking # column in TABLE2,  that is for matching records.  Although, I need to do that only for records that are NOT duplicates in TABLE2.  Meaning that row 2 and 3 in TABLE2 do not need to be updated(because they are exactly the same),  but only row 1 and 4 have to be updated.  How do I obtain that?
There are other columns too but I did not include them to make the example clearer.   The other fields that you see in the query below are the ones that make a record unique.  First of all I am not sure if the query I wrote is correct to start with, as I am having problems wrapping my head around this.  Second, the select is working and it is selecting the tracking numbers where all the values indicated match, but when I include the update I get an error:

> (“Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS”).

I would really appreciate some help, thanks

**TABLE1**

```
|Pro #| Dept|Amount  |Tracking # |  
|-----|-----|--------|-----------|  
|___2 | _35 |______5 |  ______32 |  
|___2 | _35 |_____10 |  ______35 |  
|___2 | _35 |_____10 |  ______12 |  
|___2 | _35 |______8 |  ______23 |
```

**TABLE2**

```
|Pro #| Dept  | Amount |Tracking # |  
|-----|-------|--------|-----------|  
|___2 | _35   | ______5| YES, it needs tracking #  
|___2 | _35   | _____10| NO, does not need tracking #  
|___2 | _35   | _____10| NO, does not need tracking #   
|___2 | _35   | ______8| YES, it needs tracking #
```

**Code:**

```
UPDATE FinalTbl
SET [TrackingNumber] = TempTbl.[TrackingNumber]
FROM [FedPayHistory].[dbo].[Frt_FinalNon000TEST] FinalTbl
INNER JOIN
(Select [Source]
  ,[WkEndDt]
  ,[Yr]
  ,[Season]
  ,[Per]
  ,[Wk]
  ,[Div]
  ,[ProNum]
  ,[ApptNum]
  ,[Dept]
  ,[Vend]
  ,[AllocAmt]
  ,[RTV]
  ,[KeyRec]
  ,[BatchNum]
  ,[TrackingNumber]
  ,[MatchCode]
  ,count(*) as CNT
     FROM [FedPayHistory].[dbo].[Frt_FinalNon000TEST]
     GROUP BY [Source],[WkEndDt],[Yr],[Season],[Per],[Wk],[Div],[ProNum],[ApptNum],[Dept],[Vend],[AllocAmt],[RTV],[KeyRec],[BatchNum],[TrackingNumber],[MatchCode]
     HAVING count(*)<2) JoinTable
  ON 
  FinalTbl.[Source] = JoinTable.[Source] and
  FinalTbl.[Yr] = JoinTable.[Yr] and 
  FinalTbl.[Season] = JoinTable.[Season] and
  FinalTbl.[Per] = JoinTable.[Per] and
  FinalTbl.[Wk] = JoinTable.[Wk] and
  FinalTbl.[Div] = JoinTable.[Div] and
  FinalTbl.[Dept] = JoinTable.[Dept] and 
  FinalTbl.[Vend] = JoinTable.[Vend] and
  FinalTbl.[KeyRec] = JoinTable.[KeyRec] and
  FinalTbl.[RTV] = JoinTable.[RTV] and
  FinalTbl.[AllocAmt] = JoinTable.[AllocAmt] and
  FinalTbl.[ProNum] = JoinTable.[ProNum] 

 INNER JOIN [FedPayHistory].[dbo].[Frt_tempNon000] TempTbl 
 ON FinalTbl.Source = TempTbl.Source and
 FinalTbl.[Yr] = TempTbl.[Yr] and 
 FinalTbl.[Season] = TempTbl.[Season] and
 FinalTbl.[Per] = TempTbl.[Per] and
 FinalTbl.[Wk] = TempTbl.[Wk] and
 FinalTbl.[Div] = TempTbl.[Div] and
 FinalTbl.[Dept] = TempTbl.[Dept] and 
 FinalTbl.[Vend] = TempTbl.[Vend] and
 FinalTbl.[KeyRec] = TempTbl.[KeyRec] and
 FinalTbl.[RTV] = TempTbl.[RTV] and
 FinalTbl.[AllocAmt] = TempTbl.[AllocAmt] and
 FinalTbl.[ProNum] = TempTbl.[ProNum] and
 JoinTable.[Source] = TempTbl.[Source] and
 JoinTable.[Yr] = TempTbl.[Yr] and 
 JoinTable.[Season] = TempTbl.[Season] and
 JoinTable.[Per] = TempTbl.[Per] and
 JoinTable.[Wk] = TempTbl.[Wk] and
 JoinTable.[Div] = TempTbl.[Div] and
 JoinTable.[Dept] = TempTbl.[Dept] and 
 JoinTable.[Vend] = TempTbl.[Vend] and
 JoinTable.[KeyRec] = TempTbl.[KeyRec] and
 JoinTable.[RTV] = TempTbl.[RTV] and
 JoinTable.[AllocAmt] = TempTbl.[AllocAmt] and
 JoinTable.[ProNum] = TempTbl.[ProNum]
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Your sub query returns more than 1 row. And you also have another issue there, your subquery has multiple columns, how would it know which column to use? You need to look at using an update statement with a join instead of a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this:

```
UPDATE t2
SET [TrackingNumber] = t1.[TrackingNumber]
FROM [TABLE2] t2
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ProNum,
        Dept,
        AllocAmt,
        Count(*) AS CNT
   FROM [TABLE2]
   GROUP BY ProNum,
            Dept,
            AllocAmt 
   HAVING count(*)<2
) a
 ON t2.AllocAmt =a.AllocAmt AND 
    t2.ProNum = a.ProNum AND 
    t2.dept = a.dept
INNER JOIN [TABLE1] t1 
ON t2.[Source] = t1.[Source] AND
 t2.[Yr] = t1.[Yr] AND
 t2.[Season] = t1.[Season] AND
 t2.[Per] = t1.[Per] AND
 t2.[Wk] = t1.[Wk] AND
 t2.[Div] = t1.[Div] AND
 t2.[Dept] = t1.[Dept] AND
 t2.[Vend] = t1.[Vend] AND
 t2.[KeyRec] = t1.[KeyRec] AND
 t2.[RTV] = t1.[RTV] AND
 t2.[AllocAmt] = t1.[AllocAmt] AND
 t2.[ProNum] = t1.[ProNum] AND
 a.[Dept] = t1.[Dept] AND
 a.[AllocAmt] = t1.[AllocAmt] AND
 a.[ProNum] = t1.[ProNum]
```

Comment: I added the code I have used and the image of the two tables.  All the records except two from the final table(the second one in the image) should get the tracking number from the temp table, but it is not happening.  Again, all the records from the final table should get the tracking number from the temp table, except the records in the final table that are exact duplicates(within the final table)

Comment: Nevermind my last comment.  I made a small typo error.  The code you gave me works wonderfully.  Thank you so much!